# Problems installing and booting Ubuntu/Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, ssd

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, with it being on an external hard drive. My windows installation is on an internal SSD.

I've gone through the installation but I get this message toward the end of the installation when setting the boot device as the SSD or the EUFI petition

> Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.

I am able to 'install' it fully when I set the boot device as the External hard drive, but it does not come in the boot devices in the bios. I know I am able boot from USB, as I did the installation from a live USB.

I've also tried installing grub via terminal, using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I, but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you installing in  the same boot mode, either both UEFI or both BIOS. Even if different modes you can get that type of error if partitioning and then required partitions do not match. Best to see details. Post link to summary report:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the problem was that instead of having a EFI/Legacy option in my BIOS, it listed each entity twice when selecting a boot device. All I needed to do was select "UEFI: (USB Drive Name)" when installing off the live USB.

Thanks Oldfred for helping :)